# php, how do I get a value from fetced array outside of a while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop, fetch, isset

This is my code. I want to get the fetched value outside of the while-loop. 
How can I do that?

```
while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
    {   
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>"; ?><a href='./display_images2.php?showrealsize'> <img src="<?php echo $myRow["image"];  ?>" height="100" width="100"> </a> <?php echo "</td>"; 
        echo "<td style='display: block;'>"; echo $myRow["name"]; echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }




//THIS CODE DOESNT WORK>>
    if(isset($_GET['showrealsize'])){
        echo  "<img src=" ?> <?php echo $myRow['image']; ?> <?php echo ">";
        }
```

Comment: You can't do that because $myRow is defined only within the scope of the while loop.

Comment: @Maximus2012 PHP doesn't have block scope. `$myRow` will just be set to the last value from the while loop which is likely "false" because once `$result` has no more rows `fetch_array` will return false which is how the `while` finishes.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn yes. That is the more correct explanation for this case.

Comment: Not even with sessions? :(

Comment: What does sessions have to do with this? You are setting a variable on each iteration (`$myRow`). While there are rows, `$myRow` will be an array which the `while` loop will see as "truthy" and keep looping. Once you hit the end of the rows, `fetch_array` returns false, `$myRow` is set to false and the while loop sees that as a false condition and so ends looping.

Comment: What I want to do is making an image gallery where images opens in new window with image information below.

Comment: Then do one of two things. 1) What unixmiah is suggesting. In your while loop add the row data to an array. You can then loop over that array below to build the bottom stuff. 2) Inside the while loop build the below stuff and store it in a string instead of echo'ing it out. Keep appending to that string on each loop and echo it out after.

Comment: Wait, I think I just realized something. The two bits of code are in two separate files loaded separately (as in not include()'d together), right? In that case, then this won't work as you expect. Separate requests for pages don't share variables between them. And sessions only remember what you put into the session. Turning on sessions doesn't make it automatically remember every variable from a previous load.

Comment: To make this work, you would need to add something like the image id for each image in the url. Then when someone clicks a link to the full image, that image page would get the id, query for the image information again and display whatever it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that is to capture the values in the while loop in a array and use it outside of the array when needed.

for example:

```
$capture_val = array();
while($myRow = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_query))
  $capture_val[] = ""; //store the value you want to 
                       //store in this array to use later 
                       //outside of the array
}

print_r($capture_val);
```

The key is the use an array to capture values in the while loop.

Comment: $capture_val = array();  Doesnt work. I guess, I dont know how to use it properly.  It doesnt capture anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

To expand on unixmiah's answer, you could use an array like in the following example:

```
// create the array
$arr = array();

while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
{   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>"; ?><a href='./display_images2.php?showrealsize'> <img src="<?php echo $myRow["image"];  ?>" height="100" width="100"> </a> <?php echo "</td>"; 
    echo "<td style='display: block;'>"; echo $myRow["name"]; echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $arr[$myRow['id']] = $myRow['some_value']; // adds to $arr with the row ID as a key to the element.

}
```

Then loop through the array afterwards `echo`-ing an `img` tag if that's what you're trying to achieve here.